# python isnull() or isna() both are not working

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the values with condition based on column values having values 'Y' or 'N' which is working fine and i am also checking other columns having date values in which `isnull()`  or `isna()`
not working , I have also tried with `isnull().any() or isna().any() or empty` they are not working

I am getting the error

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

this is my dataframe

[image]

this is my code

```
filteringst=st.loc[(st['Passout'] =='Y') and  (st['Passout Date'].isna().any())]
```

I have also tried like this

```
filteringst=st.loc[(st['Passout'] =='Y') and  (st['Passout Date'].isnull().any())]
```

or

```
filteringst=st.loc[(st['Passout'] =='Y') and  (st['Passout Date'].isnull())]
```

**But getting the same error**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
filteringst=st.loc[(st['Passout'] =='Y') & (st['Passout Date'].isnull())]
```

Comment: @it worked i got the error because of and , thanks for the help

Comment: well, it's the bitwise and operator, overloaded to do *vectorized logical and*.